# keyboard hierarchy is wrong when use multitasking on ipad pro

Tags: ios, ipad, multitasking

When I use multitask on ipad pro, my app's keyboard hierarchy is not right, part of the keyboard is hidden by window, like the following pic
so what is the reason? Please instruct me some tips if you have any, thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlQTF.png)

Comment: I don't know the main reason, but it seems like keyboard is acting like it is taking whole split view.